# User analytics in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

We have a large web application. We need to store user analytics about which ads has users seen. What accordions has been clicked etc. As far as I can see log analytics and application insights is more targeted towards logging and instrumentation (correct me if I am wrong). Does Azure provide any services for this kind of functionality, or would you have to store it your self to a SQL server/Table storage/CosmosDB and make a job that calculates the different statistics needed?

Comment: if "which ads has users seen" is actually a page view / request operation, then you can choose application insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "which ads has users seen" is actually a **page view** / **request** operation, then you can choose application insights.

If you're using app insights SDK, then you can track the events for these ads by using methods like [TrackEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent). This event data is useful for analytics in application insights.

For analytics, you can use [log queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview) which is available for **azure monitor** / **application insights**(to use log query, nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> in the left panel, select "Logs(Analytics)" under Monitoring). With log query, you can build your own query for any different statistics, or generate some charts.

Please let me know if you have more concerns.

Comment: Thanks. We uses Application Insights heavily. The question is more is this the right approach for user analytics too? I would properly then have to use the customDimension property to indentify what adds and accordions. And will Log Analytics make sure that data is permanent and not like AI be deleted after some time?

Comment: @ThomasSegato As far as I know, this is the correct way in azure. And for Log Analytics, the max data retention day is also [730](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2017/01/25/change-oms-log-analytics-retention-period-in-the-azure-portal/) days as application insights.